# MagicalRecord saveWithBlock - how to cancel operation

Tags: ios, magicalrecord-2.2

I'm using `MagicalRecord` with its `saveWithBlock:` method:

```
[MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext) {
    // some work
    // ...
    // -> ups! I changed my mind, I don't want to save!
}];
```

If I'd like to cancel the saving operation inside that block, how can I achieve that?

E.g. I have a long running download/sync operation when the user logs in - if the user logs out during this operation I'd like to cancel the saving inside the `saveWithBlock:`

Comment: Not possible in the context of that method. What are you actually trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to perform cancellation then don't wrap your changes into a MagicalRecord `saveWithBlock`. You could simply use the Context's `performBlock` API and discard the changes if you are not happy.

```
[context performBlock:^{
    // some work
    // ...
    if(timeToCancel) {
      [context reset];
    } else {
      [context MR_saveToPersistentStoreWithCompletion:nil];
    }
}];
```